# ASP.Net Core Web App Installation Problem (Unable to Build)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017-build-tools

I'm having issues setting up .Net Core application locally. I inherited the application folder from a developer who wants me to contribute to the project. After opening the project in my visual studio 2017, VisualStudio/15.0.0-RTW+26228.4, before building the solution, I'm getting the detailed error message in the error list window

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Unable to resolve 'Microsoft.NETCore.App (>= 3.1.0)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1'.            0

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Unable to resolve 'Microsoft.NETCore.App (>= 3.1.0)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1'.            0

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Unexpected dependency 'Microsoft.NETCore.App' with no version number.   MHealth C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\build\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets 154

Please, I will welcome your contributions. Thanking you in advance.
[VS Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pA6aq.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

what does your `dotnet --version` say in bash or powershell?

`dotnet restore`

Download .Net Core 3.1: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.1

A few cli commands: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/

You referenced 2.0 in a tag yet its showing 3.0 errors?
Where is your .csproj file?

Comment: My dotnet --version is 1.0.0

Comment: @ralph_fonz, I clicked on the link that you provided for me to Download .Net Core 3.1, but I didn't find the  SDK that supports the visual studio 2017 (15.0).

Comment: @Amechi01 might not be supported under 2017... for VS17 / VS19 you need to go through the VS installer https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/community/ (you should have it in your downloads folder) then > modify > net core apps or something > select proper version. I cant remember off the top off my head but the installer is the key for that IDE.

Comment: @Amechi01 you should be on vs19 community. i doubt 2017 is supported as well

Comment: I was able to set up the .Net Core application locally by installing the Visual Studio 2019 community edition. Thanks for your assistance @Ralph_Fonz.